# Reaching maximum content in a page using image scroll then should hide image using percentage of a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600){
        $("#bottom").addClass('show');
    } else {
        $("#bottom").removeClass('show');
    };      
});
</script>
```

```
<button type="button" onclick="scrollWin()"><img src="Images/aerodown.png"></button>
```

```
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 180);
}
```

This is my code. am set one image for scroll down when click it. The problem is when using it, in multiple devices image has been hide(But in browser the image can view and click. Is not work for mobile browsers). So i want to hide the image using percentage. Which means when it reach the 99% of a page the image should hide(am set opacity for this function). I am new to jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend to define the height as a static value. Because as soon as you add/remove something from your page you'll need to update that value manually.
Fetch the height and multiply it with your target percentage.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ejdu0oLf/1/

**Html:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="scrollBt show">BUTTON</a>
```

**JS:**

```
var $win = $(window),
    docHeight = $(document).height(), // Height of document
    winHeight = $win.height(), // Height of window
    targetPerc = docHeight * 0.9; // 0.9 = 0.9*100 = Target percentage

// Event
$(document).on('scroll', toggleButton); 

function toggleButton() {

    // Calculates the current scroll position
    var currentPos = $win.scrollTop() + $win.height();

    // Toggles the "hidden" class if the current position it more than the target percentage
    $(".scrollBt").toggleClass('hidden', currentPos >= targetPerc);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    height:1000px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.scrollBt {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    left:0;
 }

.hidden {
     display:none;   
}
```